# Extracting numbers from a string in R

Tags: r

I have a number of strings of form "857.97\t0.000". Here I am interested in extracting the numbers 857.97 and 0.000 separately. How can I go about doing this in R?

Comment: use regex to do this `[^0-9]`

Comment: `strsplit(x, "\t")`, )but how did you get the string. ie you may be able to do this at reading the data in?)

Comment: `stringr::str_extract_all("857.97\t0.000", '[\\d.-]+')`